# Is that the thread object can be moved in C++ 11 reasonable?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, move

In C++11, the thread object can be moved. As we all know, every thread we created owns a functor. Obviously, to move a thread which its functor has not been executed is reasonable. But what about moving a thread of which functor is being called or has been executed for some time?
To step further, if I implements a thread wrapper class, like:

```
//noncopyable is a tag class of which copy constructor and copy assignment are deleted.
class Thread:noncopyable{
private:
    using ThreadFunc = std::function<void()>;
    bool started_;    //used to mark whether the functor executes or not
    std::thread thread_;
    CountDownLatch latch_;
    std::string name_;
    ThreadFunc func_;
    ...
public:
    Thread(ThreadFunc func, const std::string& name)
      :func_(std::move(func)),name_(name){}
    ...
}
```

And I want to implement move operation for Thread as thread object does. Would check out the `started_` before move operation be a better choice?(Although I think it would be ten to one not) Like:

```
Thread& Thread::operation=(Thread&& rhs) noexcept{
    if(this != &rhs && !started_){
        //do something
    }
    return *this;
}
Thread::Thread(Thread&& rhs) noexcept{
    //do something
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `std::thread` does not formally own the functor it was constructed with. Rather, the functor is held by the invocation of `std::invoke` which is kicked off (in the target thread) by the constructor.

So moving a `std::thread` doesn't need to, and isn't going to, move the functor. As long as the thread is executing, the functor is alive as a local variable.

Comment: Well answered. I got another question: if the std::invoke is kicked off by the constructor, then is it a must to use latch_ to ensure the synchronous execution of functions between the main thread and the new thread?

Comment: I'm not sure what purpose `_latch` serves in your code. By the time the constructor completes, everything that needs to be copied around to get the new thread started has already been copied around.

Comment: `latch_` is a synchronizer to ensure that the main thread will wait until the functor in new thread is kicking off. For instance, the main thread will set `latch_` to 1, and functor in new thread will execute `latch_.countdown()` in the first place.  When the main thread detects that the `latch_` has changed to 0，it knows that the functor in new thread is executing.

Comment: There is no need for a thread to announce that it has started executing, since there are no practical consequences to it. The main thread should not wait for the new thread to begin execution.

Comment: I have seen such usage in some open source project, say muduo network library.  It implements a Thread class to wrap POSIX threads API. In the Thread::start function, it creates a new thread and uses `latch_` to make sure that the start function will only return until the new thread is kicking off.  I'm just wondering that if I want to implement this Thread class by std::thread instead of POSIX API, then should I keep that `latch_` variable?

Comment: In muduo, to do so is meaningful because when a user call the Thread::start and it returns,  the user will think that the new thread has been kicked off. The `latch_` shoulder this work.

Comment: There are no practical consequences to when the new thread begins execution. It does not indicate anything the main thread can use. If the main thread is worried that it might take a while for the new thread to start doing anything, then why isn't it worried that the new thread might decrement the latch and then be pre-empted by the OS for a while?

Comment: I suspect that the thread routine in the library you gave as an example is doing something *before* decrementing the latch. Whatever it's doing before that is the important part, not it beginning execution.

Comment: @PhoenixChao -- when the `thread` constructor returns, the copy of the passed-in callable object will have already begun execution. That's required by the standard. You don't need any explicit synchronization for that.

Comment: Thank you for your answer  @PeteBeckerPe